# Automatic mounting a thumb drive in 21.10

Tags: mount, 21.10

In 21.10 I have to bring up the GUI file manager to click on USB device and get it to mount in media/USER/

Is there any way to get the behavior back to just an automatic mount without having to use nautilus for mounting the USB device manually? (thumb drive or external hard drive.)

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount
true

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount` please add this to your question.

Comment: Have the same problem. Any solution yet?

Comment: same problem with audio cds, i must mount them manually to make rhythmbox see them

Comment: This behaviour may be caused by extensions, the Dash To Panel, in my case. Have you tried disabling all gnome extensions and restarting your computer?